# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied .ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

:

```
makerhan@makerhan-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
... logging to /home/makerhan/.ros/log/d3447fd4-0716-11e8-8422-44032cf50938/roslaunch-makerhan-Inspiron-15-3567-13942.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://localhost:46237/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/kinetic/...
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: /camera_depth_frame
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min: 0.45
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 10
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.12
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    laserscan_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[gazebo-1]: started with pid [13962]
process[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [13967]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-3]: started with pid [13972]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [13973]
process[cmd_vel_mux-5]: started with pid [13974]
process[bumper2pointcloud-6]: started with pid [13975]
process[robot_state_publisher-7]: started with pid [13976]
process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-8]: started with pid [13984]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-9]: started with pid [13997]
[ INFO] [1517465536.132313314]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1517465536.133011067]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model", line 32, in <module>
    import tf.transformations as tft
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tf2_ros import TransformException as Exception, ConnectivityException, LookupException, ExtrapolationException
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .buffer_interface import *
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2_ros/buffer_interface.py", line 32, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('tf2_ros')
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 62, in load_manifest
    sys.path = _generate_python_path(package_name, _rospack) + sys.path
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 93, in _generate_python_path
    m = rospack.get_manifest(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 167, in get_manifest
    return self._load_manifest(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/rospack.py", line 211, in _load_manifest
    retval = self._manifests[name] = parse_manifest_file(self.get_path(name), self._manifest_name, rospack=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg/manifest.py", line 412, in parse_manifest_file
    _static_rosdep_view = init_rospack_interface()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/rospack.py", line 58, in init_rospack_interface
    lookup = _get_default_RosdepLookup(Options())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/main.py", line 128, in _get_default_RosdepLookup
    verbose=options.verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 613, in create_default
    sources = load_cached_sources_list(sources_cache_dir=sources_cache_dir, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 510, in load_cached_sources_list
    with open(cache_index, 'r') as f:
**IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/makerhan/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index'
[spawn_turtlebot_model-3] process has died [pid 13972, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base __name:=spawn_turtlebot_model __log:=/home/makerhan/.ros/log/d3447fd4-0716-11e8-8422-44032cf50938/spawn_turtlebot_model-3.log].
log file: /home/makerhan/.ros/log/d3447fd4-0716-11e8-8422-44032cf50938/spawn_turtlebot_model-3*.log**
```

Why error??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281477/ioerror:-%5Berrno-13%5D-permission-denied-.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index/) by [MakerHanRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/33503/makerhanros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-02-01**:
maybe explaing what you are trying to do? For how to properly create a question, check out http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-01**:
A question without a question, isn't really a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See if `/home/makerhan/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache/index` already exists, or exists but permissions are incorrect on it (maybe wrongly running `sudo rosdep update` creates this problem?).

If it doesn't exist try:

```
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Initialize_rosdep

(if it does already exist, maybe delete it first then run rosdep steps again)

I'm just guessing, maybe later I'll try deleting my own and seeing if the same error comes up and update this.

https://answers.ros.org/question/175599/rosdep-update-permission-error/ looks related.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billqd](https://answers.ros.org/users/37883/billqd/) on 2019-03-27**:
I had a similar problem (I'm pretty sure I did sudo rosdep update at somepoint last week). Doing rosdep update fixed it for me. Thanks